# html email template issue

Tags: email-template

Hi i have two objects case and task,in between these am created lookup relationship now in the email template I was referring the both task fields and case fields,when I am firing a workflow the merge fields are not fetching the values......
Example

```
Hi {!Case.Name},{!Case.family name}

Hello {!Task.firstname}{!Task.LastName}
```

can u please give any suggestion that I am using the correct Syntax.

Comment: Workflow is on task or Case

Comment: Workflow is on case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If workflow is on Case, then it is impossible using Text or HTML emails to show children record merge fields (i.e. `Tasks`) because the target object in scope for the email template is the target object of the workflow

To show Tasks - and since there can be more than one Task for a Case, you'll need to think about your business logic as to which task or tasks to show.  Once having done that, you will need to:

- Make the email template a VF email template
- Create a custom component to show the related task (or tasks). The custom component uses a custom controller to fetch the related task(s) given a Case.Id that is passed to the component.

**VF template**

```
... markup for Hi! ...
<c:taskList caseId={!Case.Id}/> <!-- show tasks here in email body -->
... more markup, if any -- e.g. a footer
```

**VF component**

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="TasksController">
  <apex:attribute name="caseId" type="ID" required="true" assignTo={!csId}/>

  <apex:repeat value="{!tasks}" var="t">  <!-- can also use dataTable or straight <table> -->
     .. markup for a Task row ..
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

**Component controller**

```
public class TasksController {
  public ID csId {get; set;}  // gets value before getTasks() is called
  public Task[] getTasks() {
    return csId != null
            ? [select id, ... from Task where whatId = :csId ...]
            : new List<Task>();  // avoids preview exception
  }
}
```

Comment: so i changed the workflow from case to Task...now these time also iam not able to get the values .

Comment: @keerthanachowdhary -- So, now you can see the Task merge fields but not the Case merge fields?

Comment: what is the solution to get these two objects merge fields data..in need to move to visual force template??

Comment: @keerthanachowdhary - Unfortunately, because Task has polymorphic parent (Case, Contact, Account, etc.) you can't get Case fields if Task is the target object so, yes, VF email template with a VF custom component/controller